# Does Room automatically cache calls to compileStatement?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using Room and I like to write my own queries. I am wondering if Room automatically cache calls to compileStatement, or do I need to cache them myselfs? This is an example of my query:

```
fun updateAllowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsersAllRows(database: GeneratedDatabase, allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers: Boolean) {
    // Will this be recomputed all the time?
    val stmt = database.compileStatement("update Conversation set allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers = ?")
    assert(database.inTransaction())

    val val1 = if (allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers) { 1L } else { 0L }
    stmt.bindLong(1, val1)

    stmt.execute()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Room does not automatically cache calls to compileStatement(). Therefore, it is recommended to cache the compiled statement manually for better performance, especially if you are executing the same query multiple times in your code.

In your code, you can cache the compiled statement by storing it as a member variable of your class, and reusing it in subsequent calls to the same query.

```
private var updateStmt: SQLiteStatement? = null

fun updateAllowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsersAllRows(database: GeneratedDatabase, allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers: Boolean) {
    assert(database.inTransaction())

    if (updateStmt == null) {
        updateStmt = database.compileStatement("update Conversation set allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers = ?")
    }

    val val1 = if (allowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsers) { 1L } else { 0L }
    updateStmt?.bindLong(1, val1)

    updateStmt?.execute()
}
```

I added a member variable `updateStmt` to your class, which is initialized to `null`. In the `updateAllowMessagesByInRangeRegularUsersAllRows()` method, I first check if `updateStmt` is `null`. If it is `null`, I compile the statement using `database.compileStatement()` and assign it to `updateStmt`. If `updateStmt` is not `null`, I reuse it for subsequent calls to the same query.